# About the funtions that satisfies $f(ab)\geq b f(a) + a f(b)$

Tags: functions, information-theory

I am doing some research in information theory related to the [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) and some of their properties. So we have a convex function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(1)=0$, and from that we can deduce a lot of interesting properties regarding the associated $f$-divergence but in the end it would become handy to be able to have, for any $a$ and $b$ in $(0,\infty)$
$$f(ab)\geq b f(a) + a f(b)$$

And I'm not sure if this is a known property and/or if it is incompatible with the convexity of $f$ and the fact that $f(1)=0$.

Observe that this is true with equality for the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) as $f(t)=t\log(t)$ and $f(ab)=ab\log(ab)=ab\log(a)+ab\log(b)=b f(a)+a f(b)$

So I'm wondering if some of you have already seen something of this type or related, it would be of help.

Comment: It is closely related to the condition $h(c+d) \geq h(c)+h(d)$, $h(0)=0$ for a function $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$: take $h(x)=\frac {f(e^{x})} {e^{x}}$.

Comment: There are lots of subadditive functions $h$ vanishing at $0$ and $f(a)=-ah(log\, a)$ gives an example of a function satisfying your inequality. Your function $tlog \, t$ is the special case $h(t)=-t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the given relation,

$$\frac{f(ab)}{ab}\ge \frac{f(a)}a+\frac{f(b)}b,$$

which is in the form

$$g(ab)\ge g(a)+g(b),$$

or with $h(t):=g(e^t)$,

$$h(a+b)\ge h(a)+h(b).$$